# Add trailing slash in tcsh completion of directory symbolic links

Tags: autocomplete, tcsh

Assume I have a folder `~/Documents`

Now when I type `/Doc` and press `tab` key, my tcsh would complete the line to `/Documents`

What I would like to achieve, is to get `/Documents/`

I found most of the discussions on the Internet is about bash. But here I'm using **tcsh**. I know this is doable as my previous setup works like this in **tcsh**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how tcsh should behave by default; but it's controlled with the `addsuffix` setting; from `tcsh(1)`:

```
   addsuffix (+)
           If set, filename completion adds `/' to the end of directories
           and a space to the end of normal files when they are matched
           exactly.  Set by default.
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves the problem. Somehow this variable is disable by default in my env. After adding this one in .cshrc, I get the behavior I want.